# Is it possible to query messages that were sent with notify-send?

Tags: logs, notifications, libnotify

I want to query the messages that were already sent with `notify-send` in the running session from within a script. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think you can unless you start listening to notifications (at session start-up, that is) and log them to a file.

Comment: What approach would enable me 'to listen' to libnotify processes?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89279/listening-to-incoming-libnotify-notifications-using-dbus)... You'll have to adapt those python scripts to your needs (extract only the message text and save it to a log file)

Comment: @don_crissti That should be an answer.